# how can I make a boost::filesystem::path case insensitive

Tags: c++, stl, filepath, boost-filesystem

can anyone enlighten me as to how I can make a **boost::filesystem::path** case insensitive?  Normally, case sensitivity is a **native** platform decision, however this is not quite so simple for my application as the path details are extracted from a binary file, and the application requirement is that no matter what platform I am running on, I have to treat all paths case insensitively.

The way I have been doing this to date is to use the **boost::filesystem::path::generic_string()** method to put paths that I am comparing into a common string format for lexicographical comparison. Next, I convert the strings lower case and use std::string functions to perform the comparisons and other operator methods.  Obviously this is sub-optimal as I would like to be able to perform lexicographical comparisons on the **paths** and not on the **strings**.  Internally, boost's path **operator<()** implementation uses a clever lexicographical path comparison using path's iterators - this is different to string lexicographical comparisons.

I thought there was some way providing a special user defined string type as the internal representation to boost path in the construcor, but I am not sure how to do this.  Normally, case insensitivity of this nature would be performed through the associated traits classes - as you can see below in a case insensitive string traits character class used for a UtlCIString (utility case insensitive string).  If it were possible to associate a different string type as the internal string class I would use the following, but I am not sure how:

```
// case insensitive character traits
// inherited copy (preserves case),
// case insensitive comparison, search
struct traits_nocase : std::char_traits<char>
{
    static bool eq(const char& c1, const char& c2) {
        return toupper(c1) == toupper(c2);
    }
    static bool lt(const char& c1, const char& c2) {
        return toupper(c1) < toupper(c2);
    }
    static int compare(const char* s1, const char* s2, size_t N) {
#if defined (_WIN32)
        return _strnicmp(s1, s2, N);
#else // POSIX
        return strncasecmp( s1, s2, N );
#endif
    }
    static const char* find(const char* s, size_t N, const char& a) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            if (toupper(s[i]) == toupper(a)) {
                return s + i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    static bool eq_int_type(const int_type& c1, const int_type& c2) {
        return toupper(c1) == toupper(c2);
    }
};

// string preserves case; comparisons are case insensitive
typedef std::basic_string<char, traits_nocase> UtlCIString;
```

Comment: Why the down-vote?  I think this is a very legitimate question that was clearly expressed and most importantly that has not been answered before, I also did my research and provided my findings above along with code that might help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: use [`boost::filesystem::directory_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator) and find paths yourself.

Long answer: don't.

How do you propose to handle situations where the user legitimately has multiple files in a given path with identical names other than case?

What do you think will happen when the user specifically tells you to use *one* of those files but, through your <s>superiorly infallible</s> assumed knowledge of what the user "wants" decided to use the *other* path instead?

Why are you using/targeting a filesystem with case sensitivity if you think you should not?

Comment: the "requrements" of the application are that the files on the file-system MUST be treated with case insensitivity.  :) with the crossed out words!  The binary file typically contains paths and extensions that can have a different case to the corresponding paths and file-names on the local filesystem.  I have no control over this, in my case this a binary file authoring problem that I have to work around.  I already have a sub-optimal workaround for this but it uses std::string's lex comparison and I would like path lex comparisons (which already exist albeit using case sensitive std::strings)